# Get exception information in mule catch exception strategy

Tags: exception, mule, mule-studio

I am using  catch exception strategy in my mule flow(v3.7.3).If an exception is thrown in my flow .I want to retrieve the exception in catch exception strategy.

Mule exception flow:

```
<choice-exception-strategy
        doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy
            when="exception.causedBy(com.nc.exception.NcException)"
            doc:name="Notification Center Exception Strategy">
            <custom-transformer
                class="com.zoto.nc.transformer.json.ExceptionTransformer" doc:name="Exception Transformer">
            </custom-transformer>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

In my ExceptionTransformer.java i want to handle the exception and get the exception object(to print the stacktrace)

ExceptionTransformer.java

```
public class ExceptionTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

private static org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionTransformer.class);

@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
    // Need caught exception trace here.
    try {
        LOG.info("Initiating Transformer for Exception Response" + message.getPayloadAsString());
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.info("Request landed at :" + new Date());
    return message.getPayload();
}
```

Is there a way to get the exception stacktrace in the ExceptionTrasformer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is ask the MuleMessage for it's ExceptionPayload, which has the thrown exception where you can get the trace. That is `message.getExceptionPayload()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to retrieve exception payload from MuleEventContext also?

Comment: Yes, because you can ask it for it's message. In that case it would be ```eventContext.getMessage().getExceptionPayload()```.